# C# Lambda Join Retrieve First Row Values

Tags: c#, lambda, left-join

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2. Table1 has 1 to many relationship with Table2. 
Table1 has ListId, ListName 
Table2 has FirstName, LastName, Phone, ListId, CustomField1, CustomField2

What I want to retrieve is All rows from Table1 but only retrieve CustomField2 value of Table2 for only 1st row.

The existing query I have below is retrieving me all rows from Table2 which I do not want.

```
 var result = _db.Lists
                .Join(_db.ListUsers, c => c.ListID, d => d.ListID, (c, d) => new { c, d });
```

My final resultset need to look like this
Table1.ListId, Table1.ListName, Table2.CustomField2 
1, first list, "abc" 
2, second list, "def"

Comment: You need to perform a left join.

Comment: I guess I am struggling with that left join...I can easily achieve this in tsql using CTEs and left joins but not having much success here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, get only the first record on the right table:

```
from i in _db.Lists
let p = _db.ListUsers.Where(p2 => i.ListID == p2.ListID).FirstOrDefault()
select new
{
  ListID = i.ListID,
  ListName = i.ListName,
  CustomField2  = p.CustomField2
}
```

With lambda expression, it would be:

```
_db.Lists
.Select (
  i => 
     new  
     {
        i = i, 
        p = _db.ListUsers
           .Where (p2 => i.ListID == p2.ListID))
           .Take(1)
           .FirstOrDefault()
     })
  .Select (
  results => 
     new  
     {
        ListID= results.i.ListID,
        ListName = results.i.ListName,
        CustomField2 = results.p.CustomField2
     }
```

)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  It definitely led to the solution I was looking for. Thank you all for contributing so promptly.

Comment: Good to help :) @Nizar

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, the result you want to achieve is retrieve a list of results contains  **All columns from Table1 & 1 column from Table2 (Not rows)**.

There are few ways to do this. I would use create a DTO class to retrieve my results. And in the select , you would need to specifically list out the item in your select result.
For example, 
Create a DTO class

```
public class DTOListResult
{
 public string XXX {get; set;}
 ...
}
```

Then in your result, you can write in this way.

```
  var result = (from a in _db.Lists select new DTOListResult { XXX = _db.table2.ID,
xxx = a.ID,
XXX = a.XX});
```

Comment: That is the eventual goal but I am not there yet. Because of 1 to many relationship I am getting all rows from Table2.